# 404 Page not showing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a page to be accessible by id e.g `http:/localhost/v2/indicator/details/directives/4`

however when I remove the `id` e.g  `http:/localhost/v2/indicator/details/directives` or `http:/localhost/v2/indicator/details/directives/mail.html` it still tries to access the page and gives me errors. **I want it to give me a 404 not found page which i have.**

Error

```
 Message: Missing argument 2 for Indicator::details()

 Filename: controllers/Indicator.php

 Line Number: 140

 Backtrace:

 File: C:\wamp\www\v2\application\controllers\Indicator.php Line: 140
 Function: _error_handler

 File: C:\wamp\www\v2\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
 Severity: Notice

 Message: Undefined variable: id

 Filename: controllers/Indicator.php

 Line Number: 154

 Backtrace:

 File: C:\wamp\www\v2\application\controllers\Indicator.php Line: 154
 Function: _error_handler

 File: C:\wamp\www\v2\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
```

Controller section for details

```
 public function details($directive, $id) {

        $this->data['current_user_menu'] = '';
        if($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin'))
        {


        $data['user'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        $data['indicators']  = $this->core->getIndicators(); 
        // load views and send data
        $this->data['current_user_menu'] = $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->data['current_user_menu'] = $this->load->view('templates/view_indicator', $data);
        $this->data['current_user_menu'] = $this->load->view('footer_main');
       }
       else
       {
         //If no session, redirect to login page
         redirect('auth/login');
       }
    }
```

**the view has**

```
<?php $in_id = $this->uri->segment(4);?>
```

**Custom 404 Controller**

```
    class My404 extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() 
    {
        $this->layout->set_body_attr(array('class' => 'gray-bg'));

        $this->layout->add_css_files(array('bootstrap.min.css'), base_url().'assets/css/');
        $this->layout->add_css_files(array('font-awesome.css'), base_url().'assets/font-awesome/css/');
        $this->layout->add_css_files(array('animate.css','style.css'), base_url().'assets/css/');
        $this->output->set_status_header('404');
        $this->load->view('404');//loading in my template 
    } 
}
```

Comment: We can't dream about your code , you should post your ` Indicator::details()` controller's code.

Comment: @ArshSingh I have done some edit i don't if that will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**Functions**

1. [`is_int` in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)
2. [`empty` in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
3. [`show_404` in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html#show_404)

---

**In indicator Controller**

```
public function details($directive, $id) {

    if (!is_int($id) || empty($id)) 
    {
        show_404();
    } 
    else {
        $this->data['current_user_menu'] = '';
        if($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin'))
        {
            $data['user'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
            $data['indicators']  = $this->core->getIndicators(); 
            // load views and send data
            $this->data['current_user_menu'] = $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->data['current_user_menu'] = $this->load->view('templates/view_indicator', $data);
            $this->data['current_user_menu'] = $this->load->view('footer_main');
        }
        else
        {
            //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('auth/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd make the `$id` argument optional, as that seems to be the crux of the problem.  `public function details($directive, $id = null)`

Comment: My 404 is custom and has a controller...how do i call it.

**SEE EDIT**

Comment: use **redirect** like this ` redirect('auth/login');`

Comment: @Abdulla redirect works for `http:/localhost/v2/indicator/details/directives` but not `http:/localhost/v2/indicator/details/directives/mail.html`

Comment: @DanielOmara sorry. Change this `if (!is_int($id) || empty($id))`

Comment: @DanielOmara any luck ??

Comment: @DanielOmara happy to help :)